# Specifying artifactsLocation in web app deployment to Azure

Tags: azure, octopus-deploy

I am trying to deploy an Azure Resource group via Octopus Deploy (within it a website).

Hyak.Common.CloudException: InvalidTemplate: Deployment template validation failed: 'The value for the template parameter '_artifactsLocation' at line '40' and column '32' is not provided.

How would I specify this in Visual Studio so that the solution can get deployed to Azure?

Thanks

Comment: `_artifactsLocation` you don't provide this value in template.  You could set a default value when you add it.

Answer (score 1):

From an Octopus point-of-view, you can use [variable substitution](https://octopus.com/docs/reference/variable-substitution-syntax) on both the Template and Parameter files to sub in whatever values you need to your templates.

If you have a look at the "Template Contained in a Package" section of the [Azure Resource Groups documentation](https://octopus.com/docs/guides/azure-deployments/resource-groups), it shows you example JSON templates with variable substitution in place.

Eg.

```
"databaseName": {
    "value": "#{DatabaseName}"
},
```

So in your project, you'd setup a project variable, then use the variable substitution syntax to address that variable in your template JSON (that's contained in your package), and it will get substituted before being executed at Azure.

Hope this helps